# Book: Young man attacked by wild animal (bear?) and rescued by shifted werewolf-woman (princess?), changed to be rescued, existing betrothal

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

I'm looking for a book in English.

It starts with a young man/teenaged boy being attacked by some wild animal (bear?) in the wilderness and he's severely injured.  A wolf - a shifted werewolf girl/woman - either rescues him from the bear or find him injured.  To save his life, she bites and infects him (or something).  The boy stumbles to his car and drives away.  Not sure if he turns into a werewolf (didn't get that far).

I also seem to remember some stunning eyes...  Either the boy got some special eyes, or the boy sees the special eyes of the werewolf...

The werewolf is some sort of a werewolf-princess, and she's out hunting together with a female friend (also a werewolf) - who is a bit timid.  The friend berates the princess for saving the boy.

The princess falls instantly in love with the boy, but she's already promised to another - a male werewolf... possibly the "prince" of another pack.

I think the boy maybe goes to school (high school?) - and perhaps the boy starts at the princess' school or vice versa.

I didn't really get much further in this book - just read a few chapters - but does anybody knows what book this might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

The book I was thinking of is "Nightshade" by Andrea Cremer.

[image: Nightshade by Andrea Cremer]

> Calla Tor has always known her destiny: After graduating from 
>   the Mountain School, she'll be the mate of sexy alpha wolf 
>   Ren Laroche and fight with him, side by side, ruling their pack 
>   and guarding sacred sites for the Keepers. But when she violates 
>   her master's laws by saving a beautiful human boy out for a hike, 
>   Calla begins to question her fate, her existence, and the very 
>   essence of the world she has known. By following her heart, she 
>   might lose everything-including her own life. Is forbidden love 
>   worth the ultimate sacrifice?

It's apparently first in a series.  It's also available with an
alternate cover, as depicted at [GoodReads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7402393-nightshade).

[image: Nightshade - alternate cover]